swagger hide endpoints on specific user
Im trying to hide which endpoints are shown in swagger depending on which users are logged in.  This is not working and i don't understand why. Im using microsoft identity and swashbuckle In the HideEndpointsBasedOnUserFilter class the code is hitting the "if (!isUserInRole)" and goes into this but the commands inside are not removing the swagger endbpoint . Here is my code:
[SwaggerHide("Admin")]
[HttpGet]
[Route("cabinetGatewaySvc/accesscontrol/{clientId}/{cardId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> AccessControl(string clientId, string cardId)
{
_twoTraceLogger.LogTrace("CabinetController gets called");
var result = await _canOpenPort.ValidateWearerAsync(clientId, cardId);
return Ok(result);
}


namespace MsCabinetGateway.SwaggerConfig
{
public class SwaggerHideAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string RequiredRole { get; set; }

    public SwaggerHideAttribute(string requiredRole)
    {
        RequiredRole = requiredRole;
    }
}
}

public class HideEndpointsBasedOnUserFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public HideEndpointsBasedOnUserFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;

        if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return; // No authenticated user, skip filtering
        }

        // Check if the action has the SwaggerHideAttribute
        var hideAttribute = context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerHideAttribute 
        ();
        if (hideAttribute != null)
        {
            var requiredRole = hideAttribute.RequiredRole;
            var isUserInRole = user.IsInRole(requiredRole);

            // Log the roles and required role
            Console.WriteLine($"Required role: {requiredRole}, Is user in role: 
            {isUserInRole}");

            // If the user doesn't have the required role, hide the endpoint
            if (!isUserInRole)
            {
               
                operation.Tags.Clear(); // Hide operation by removing tags
                operation.Summary = null; // Optionally clear the summary
                operation.Description = null; // Optionally clear the description
                operation.Responses.Clear(); // Optionally clear responses
                
            }
        }
    }



}
}

 public class Program
 {
 private static AppSettings? ApplicationSettings { get; set; }
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
     var connectionString = 
     builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MsCabinetGatewayContextConnection") ?? 
     throw 
     new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 
    'MsCabinetGatewayContextConnection' 
    not 
    found.");

     builder.Services.AddDbContext<MsCabinetGatewayContext>(options => 
     options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
     builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
     builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<Areas.Identity.Data.MsCabinetGatewayUser> 
     (options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = 
     true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MsCabinetGatewayContext>();
     IConfiguration configuration = builder.Configuration;
     ApplicationSettings = new AppSettings();
     configuration.Bind(ApplicationSettings);

     builder.Services.AddControllers();
     // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at 
     https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
     builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
     builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
         c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
         {
             Title = "Cabinet gateway",
             Version = "v1",
             Description = "Cabinet gateway documentation."
         });

         c.OperationFilter<HideEndpointsBasedOnUserFilter>();

         // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
         var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
         var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
         c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

         c.EnableAnnotations();
         c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
         {
             Name = "Authorization",
             Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
             Scheme = "Bearer",
             BearerFormat = "JWT",
             In = ParameterLocation.Header,
             Description = 
          Adapters.RestApiAdapter.Constants.RestProperties.Description,
         });
         c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
             {
                 new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                     Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                         Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                             Id = "Bearer"
                     }
                 },
                 new string[] {}
             }

          });
         builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
     });
 
 builder.Services.AddCustomConfiguration(configuration);
         if (ApplicationSettings.AppInsightConfig is null)
         {
             ApplicationSettings.AppInsightConfig = new();
             ApplicationSettings.AppInsightConfig.InstrumentationKey =
                 
configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").GetSection("InstrumentationKey").Value;
             ApplicationSettings.AppInsightConfig.ConnectionString =
                    
configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
         }
         builder.Services.AddServiceDependencies(ApplicationSettings);

         //builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
         //{
         //    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
         //});


         builder.Services.AddLogging(builder =>
         {
             // Only Application Insights is registered as a logger provider
             builder.AddApplicationInsights(
                 configureTelemetryConfiguration:
                 (config) => config.ConnectionString = 
            configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"],
                 configureApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions: (options) => { }
             );
         });

         var app = builder.Build();

         GrpcAdapterExtention.AddServiceConfigurations(app);
     //app.Use(async (context, next) =>
     //{
     //    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger")
     //        && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     //    {
     //        context.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Login");
     //        return;
     //    }
     //    await next();
     //});
     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseAuthorization();
     app.MapRazorPages();
     app.UseStaticFiles();
     app.UseSwagger();
         app.UseSwaggerUI();
         app.UseSwagger(c =>
         {
             c.RouteTemplate = "cabinetGatewaySvc/swagger/{documentname}/swagger.json";
         });


         app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
         {
             c.SwaggerEndpoint("/cabinetGatewaySvc/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Cabinet 
         Gateway Microservice");
             c.RoutePrefix = "cabinetGatewaySvc/swagger";
         });

         app.UseRouting();


         app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
         {
             _ = endpoints.MapControllers();
         });
         app.Run();

     
  }
  }


The user does the logon on the swagger page or are you guaranteeing that only authenticated user can reach the endpoint? Can they log out on the swagger page and stay there? Presumably you missed a relevant part of the story here.

yes I'm securing that only users that are logged in can reach the swagger page

Actually the hidden endpoint is getting shown under the default listing in swagger

More or less guessing but presumably you need a IDocumentFilter not an IOperationFilter there you should be able to remove the Operation from the Swagger Document.

As suggested by @Ralf in the comments, you need to use an IDocumentFilter not an IOperationFilter to remove the Swagger endpoints.
